# Software to visualize pdb file

Tags: data-visualization

There is a file called protein data bank (.pdb) which contains the instructions for protein 
I found a video in which it shows the visualization of the pdb file.
But I am not sure what software or tools are available to visualize the pdb file.

Answer (score 1):

As you don't way which sort of visualization you are looking for I am unsure what exactly you need.

You might find [rstoolbox](https://lpdi-epfl.github.io/rstoolbox/) (discussed [here](https://bmcbioinformatics.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12859-019-2796-3#Abs1)) useful. The tutorial shows an example of [loading a PDB file](https://lpdi-epfl.github.io/rstoolbox/tutorials/sequence_analysis.html#loading-a-reference) and produces a number of visualizations:
[image: Vis1]

[Biopython](http://biopython.org/) can also read PDB files, (amongst others), and can write to [OpenSCAD](http://www.openscad.org/) format files which are suitable for 3D visualization or printing on with a 3D printer. (See https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:3957471 for an example)

[BioStructMap](https://github.com/andrewguy/biostructmap) also looks to be relevant.

Note that Python, Jupyter and all of the other tools mentioned are available free, gratis & Open Source on most platforms.